# Why is the energy-band diagram affected by nonuniform doping?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

In [Semiconductor Physics and Devices](http://dl1.ponato.com/eb1/9__b308c8a.pdf) by Donald A. Naemen (pg. 176) the following figure appears:

[image: Energy-band diagram for nonuniform doping]

The donor concentration is a decreasing function of x.

**My question**: why are the energies of the conduction and valence band ($E_c$ and $E_v$) a function of the concentration?  Why is the Fermi-level the only value in the figure that is not affected by the non-uniform distribution of donors?

Comment: $E_{fi}$ is the intrinsic Fermi energy at mid gap. $E_{f}$ is the result of varying the doping. To be in equilibrium the Fermi energy is constant across the material. So, what is your confusion more specifically?

Comment: I understand why $E_f$  is constant, and why $E_{fi}$ varies. I don't understand why $E_c$ and $E_v$  vary with donor concentrations.

Comment: Because in equilibrium the Fermi energy has to be constant across the material. What does the band diagram look like across a $pn$ junction? The Fermi energy is constant, the conduction and valence bands bend.

Comment: How do we know that the material is in equilibrium?

Answer (score 2):

Due to concentration difference there is a flow of mobile charge Carrier from region of higher concentration to lower concentration this results into diffusion current in the s/c.
Thus there is a potential generated which energises the charge carriers according to Energy=-q.V (q=e)
Due to this energy we see the Ec Ei and Ev are bent
Now coming to the Fermi energy level : as the semiconductor is in equilibrium the net current is zero therefore no electron flow happens in equilibrium and the Fermi energy level stays flat.
In conclusion the Ec/Ev/Ei bend due to diffusion owing to concentration difference while Fermi level remains flat due to equilibrium condition.

Comment: Thank you , so $E_i$ bends because its defined to be at the middle of $Ec$ and $Ev$?

Comment: How do we know that the material is in equilibrium?